# Java project in Eclipse showing unrelated jar files

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm creating a new java project and the folder shows a list of all jar files in some folder in Program Files\IBM\SPSS...

How can I get rid of those?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top menu, go to: Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. If SPSS jre is listed there remove it and add the jre you wanted to use

Answer (score 0):

right click at your project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries

select jar files you don't need then click remove

Comment: I see the jars there but the Remove button is inactive. And I want these files not to appear in a new project rather than removing them later.